# Filtering 2 arrays not returning empty when equal

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays which I am trying to filter out objects do not that exist within the first array. Currently it filters properly when the second isn't equal to the first. I need to return an empty array if both arrays are equal. Any ideas please?

```
let array1 =[
   { "id": 1, "name": "a"},
   { "id": 2, "name": "b"},
   { "id": 3, "name": "c"},
   { "id": 4, "name": "d"},
 ];

let array2 =[
   { "id": 1, "name": "a"},
   { "id": 2, "name": "b"},
   { "id": 3, "name": "c"},
   { "token": 4, "name": "d"}, 
];

result = array1.filter(x => array2.find(y => x.id !== (y.id || y.token 
         )));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is flawed, you have to negate the `find` call which actually should be `some`:

```
 array1.filter(x => !array2.some(y => x.id === (y.id || y.token )));
```

The opposite would also work:

```
array1.filter(x => array2.every(y => x.id !== (y.id || y.token)));
```